# I can not access my PowerShell parameters returned by a web service

Tags: xml, web-services, powershell

I have created a short PowerShell script to pull down some XML from a web service. This seems to work.  I've run a tcpdump and can see the correct XML returned.  If I run get-member I see all the correct parameters.  However, when I try and output any of these parameters I don't see anything.  There is no error, it just seems to be outputting nothing.

```
Function Get-AssetByMacAddress {
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$mac
)
$username = "abc"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'xyz' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)
$uri = "http://mywebservice.com/assetservice.asmx?WSDL"

# print password (testing)
$cred.GetNetworkCredential().password

# Create web service
$phatWebService = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $uri -Credential $cred -Namespace "PhatWebService"

# Call method
$phatWebService.GetAssetByMacAddress($mac)

}

$xml = Get-AssetByMacAddress -mac "90:b1:1c:61:8e:41"
$xml | get-member
Write-Host "**************************"
Write-Host $xml.CurrencyCodeBook
```

Output is shown below:

```
   TypeName: System.String

Name             MemberType            Definition                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
----             ----------            ----------                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Clone            Method                System.Object Clone()                                                                                                                                                                                                       
CompareTo        Method                int CompareTo(System.Object value), int CompareTo(string strB)                                                                                                                                                              
Contains         Method                bool Contains(string value)                                                                                                                                                                                                 
CopyTo           Method                System.Void CopyTo(int sourceIndex, char[] destination, int destinationIndex, int count)                                                                                                                                    
EndsWith         Method                bool EndsWith(string value), bool EndsWith(string value, System.StringComparison comparisonType), bool EndsWith(string value, bool ignoreCase, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)                                    
Equals           Method                bool Equals(System.Object obj), bool Equals(string value), bool Equals(string value, System.StringComparison comparisonType)                                                                                                
GetEnumerator    Method                System.CharEnumerator GetEnumerator()                                                                                                                                                                                       
GetHashCode      Method                int GetHashCode()                                                                                                                                                                                                           
GetType          Method                type GetType()                                                                                                                                                                                                              
GetTypeCode      Method                System.TypeCode GetTypeCode()                                                                                                                                                                                               
IndexOf          Method                int IndexOf(char value), int IndexOf(char value, int startIndex), int IndexOf(char value, int startIndex, int count), int IndexOf(string value), int IndexOf(string value, int startIndex), int IndexOf(string value, int...
IndexOfAny       Method                int IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf), int IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex), int IndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex, int count)                                                                                         
Insert           Method                string Insert(int startIndex, string value)                                                                                                                                                                                 
IsNormalized     Method                bool IsNormalized(), bool IsNormalized(System.Text.NormalizationForm normalizationForm)                                                                                                                                     
LastIndexOf      Method                int LastIndexOf(char value), int LastIndexOf(char value, int startIndex), int LastIndexOf(char value, int startIndex, int count), int LastIndexOf(string value), int LastIndexOf(string value, int startIndex), int LastI...
LastIndexOfAny   Method                int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf), int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex), int LastIndexOfAny(char[] anyOf, int startIndex, int count)                                                                             
Normalize        Method                string Normalize(), string Normalize(System.Text.NormalizationForm normalizationForm)                                                                                                                                       
PadLeft          Method                string PadLeft(int totalWidth), string PadLeft(int totalWidth, char paddingChar)                                                                                                                                            
PadRight         Method                string PadRight(int totalWidth), string PadRight(int totalWidth, char paddingChar)                                                                                                                                          
Remove           Method                string Remove(int startIndex, int count), string Remove(int startIndex)                                                                                                                                                     
Replace          Method                string Replace(char oldChar, char newChar), string Replace(string oldValue, string newValue)                                                                                                                                
Split            Method                string[] Split(Params char[] separator), string[] Split(char[] separator, int count), string[] Split(char[] separator, System.StringSplitOptions options), string[] Split(char[] separator, int count, System.StringSplit...
StartsWith       Method                bool StartsWith(string value), bool StartsWith(string value, System.StringComparison comparisonType), bool StartsWith(string value, bool ignoreCase, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)                              
Substring        Method                string Substring(int startIndex), string Substring(int startIndex, int length)                                                                                                                                              
ToCharArray      Method                char[] ToCharArray(), char[] ToCharArray(int startIndex, int length)                                                                                                                                                        
ToLower          Method                string ToLower(), string ToLower(System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)                                                                                                                                                  
ToLowerInvariant Method                string ToLowerInvariant()                                                                                                                                                                                                   
ToString         Method                string ToString(), string ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider)                                                                                                                                                         
ToUpper          Method                string ToUpper(), string ToUpper(System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)                                                                                                                                                  
ToUpperInvariant Method                string ToUpperInvariant()                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Trim             Method                string Trim(Params char[] trimChars), string Trim()                                                                                                                                                                         
TrimEnd          Method                string TrimEnd(Params char[] trimChars)                                                                                                                                                                                     
TrimStart        Method                string TrimStart(Params char[] trimChars)                                                                                                                                                                                   
Chars            ParameterizedProperty char Chars(int index) {get;}                                                                                                                                                                                                
Length           Property              System.Int32 Length {get;}                                                                                                                                                                                                  

**************************


   TypeName: PhatWebService.AssetInfo

Name                 MemberType Definition                                             
----                 ---------- ----------                                             
Equals               Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                         
GetHashCode          Method     int GetHashCode()                                      
GetType              Method     type GetType()                                         
ToString             Method     string ToString()                                      
AssetLife            Property   System.Decimal AssetLife {get;set;}                    
BookValue            Property   System.Decimal BookValue {get;set;}                    
ChildAssets          Property   PhatWebService.AssetInfo[] ChildAssets {get;set;}      
ChildrenCount        Property   System.Int32 ChildrenCount {get;set;}                  
CurrencyCodeBook     Property   System.String CurrencyCodeBook {get;set;}              
CurrencyCodePurchase Property   System.String CurrencyCodePurchase {get;set;}          
CurrencyCodeWritten  Property   System.String CurrencyCodeWritten {get;set;}           
DateCreated          Property   System.DateTime DateCreated {get;set;}                 
DepreciationFactor   Property   System.Decimal DepreciationFactor {get;set;}           
ExternalID           Property   System.String ExternalID {get;set;}                    
ExternalID2          Property   System.String ExternalID2 {get;set;}                   
ExternallyOwned      Property   System.Int16 ExternallyOwned {get;set;}                
Fullname             Property   System.String Fullname {get;set;}                      
Hostname             Property   System.String Hostname {get;set;}                      
HttpPort             Property   System.Int32 HttpPort {get;set;}                       
HttpsPort            Property   System.Int32 HttpsPort {get;set;}                      
ID                   Property   System.Int32 ID {get;set;}                             
InstallationScript   Property   System.String InstallationScript {get;set;}            
InstallationScriptID Property   System.Int32 InstallationScriptID {get;set;}           
IP                   Property   System.String IP {get;set;}                            
IsExpensed           Property   System.Boolean IsExpensed {get;set;}                   
IsMonitored          Property   System.Boolean IsMonitored {get;set;}                  
IsObsolete           Property   System.Boolean IsObsolete {get;set;}                   
Label                Property   System.String Label {get;set;}                         
LastDepreciation     Property   System.DateTime LastDepreciation {get;set;}            
LastHeard            Property   System.String LastHeard {get;set;}                     
Line                 Property   PhatWebService.LineInfo Line {get;set;}                
LineID               Property   System.Int32 LineID {get;set;}                         
Location             Property   System.String Location {get;set;}                      
MacAddress           Property   System.String MacAddress {get;set;}                    
MaintPort            Property   System.Int32 MaintPort {get;set;}                      
Manufacturer         Property   PhatWebService.ManufacturerInfo Manufacturer {get;set;}
ParentID             Property   System.Int32 ParentID {get;set;}                       
Password             Property   System.String Password {get;set;}                      
PrinterAssetID       Property   System.Int32 PrinterAssetID {get;set;}                 
PurchaseValue        Property   System.Decimal PurchaseValue {get;set;}                
RefreshRate          Property   System.String RefreshRate {get;set;}                   
ResolutionX          Property   System.String ResolutionX {get;set;}                   
ResolutionY          Property   System.String ResolutionY {get;set;}                   
RoleID               Property   System.Int32 RoleID {get;set;}                         
SalvageValue         Property   System.Decimal SalvageValue {get;set;}                 
SerialNo             Property   System.String SerialNo {get;set;}                      
SiteID               Property   System.Int32 SiteID {get;set;}                         
SoftwareVersion      Property   System.String SoftwareVersion {get;set;}               
SSHPort              Property   System.Int32 SSHPort {get;set;}                        
Status               Property   System.String Status {get;set;}                        
Tag                  Property   System.String Tag {get;set;}                           
TelnetPort           Property   System.Int32 TelnetPort {get;set;}                     
UserIDCreated        Property   System.Int32 UserIDCreated {get;set;}                  
Username             Property   System.String Username {get;set;}                      
VNCPort              Property   System.Int32 VNCPort {get;set;}                        
WarrantyEnd          Property   System.DateTime WarrantyEnd {get;set;}                 
WarrantyStart        Property   System.DateTime WarrantyStart {get;set;}               
WrittenDownValue     Property   System.Decimal WrittenDownValue {get;set;}
```

For some reason it's just showing me all the member properties again when I try to view the property "CurrencyCodeBook".

A couple of Google searches suggested I needed to define the web service method as [xml]

E.g.

```
    [xml]$phatWebService.GetAssetByMacAddress($mac)
```

... but this just gives me an error "Data at the root level is invalid"

Comment: try this instead : `[xml]$xml = Get-AssetByMacAddress -mac "90:b1:1c:61:8e:41"` in your code get-member tells $xml is a string not an xml object

Comment: A long shot, but you could try `Write-Host $xml.CurrencyCodeBook()`

Comment: Another thing to try; instead of `$xml | get-member`, try `gm -inputObject $xml`. This can sometimes give more accurate results.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
$wsdl = "http://mywebservice.com/assetservice.asmx?WSDL"     
$proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $wsdl -Namespace WebServiceProx
$sample = $proxy.GetAssetByMacAddress($mac)
[xml]$xmlfile = $sample
```

Now get the values

```
$fullName = $xmlfile.AssetInfo.FullName
$hostName = $xmlfile.AssetInfo.HostName
$httpPort = $xmlfile.AssetInfo.HttpPort
```

OR

```
$fullName = $xmlfile.FullName
$hostName = $xmlfile.HostName
$httpPort = $xmlfile.HttpPort
```

EDIT:

try checking your xml file. Can you post the xml file here?

Comment: Unfortunately no joy.  I get the same error: Cannot convert value "WebServiceProx.AssetInfo" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."